# Get the position of imageview dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, frame, bounds

I need to get the dynamic x,y position of the image view.
I have tried this

self.imgView.bounds.origin.y

and

self.imgView.frame.origin.x

I am getting 0.0 all the time.

How can i get this?

Thanks

Comment: show your imageview on the storyboard. did you add imageview from (0,0) in storyboard?

Comment: What do you mean under "dynamic"?

Comment: I think you need UIImage position  ?

Comment: @JonSnow Yes i need image view position.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS No I did not add it from (0,0) in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds.origin of any view should be (0,0) at all times since it is the coordinate system of the view itself (relative to its origin)

The frame.origin is in the coordinate system of the its superview, so if it's 0,0, then that might be that its origin is at its superview's origin.

Maybe you want to know the origin with respect to the screen?  If so,

```
let posInWindow = v.convert(v.bounds.origin, to: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to get rect in `UIImageVIew` 
This code in **swift3** And your ImageViewContentMode should be Aspect fit

```
 func calculateRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: UIImageView) -> CGRect {
    let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
    let imgSize = imageView.image?.size

    guard let imageSize = imgSize, imgSize != nil else {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    let scaleWidth = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width
    let scaleHeight = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height
    let aspect = fmin(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

    var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width * aspect, height: imageSize.height * aspect)
    // Center image
    imageRect.origin.x = (imageViewSize.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2
    imageRect.origin.y = (imageViewSize.height - imageRect.size.height) / 2

    // Add imageView offset
    imageRect.origin.x += imageView.frame.origin.x
    imageRect.origin.y += imageView.frame.origin.y

    return imageRect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bounds will always return an x and y of 0, you want to use frame. In your example these values may be correct? Try adding your imageView in the centre of the view and logging the:

```
self.imgView.frame.origin.x
self.imgView.frame.origin.y
```